# Web page degradation when partially refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help and or hints.

We've a page that refreshes every second. In theory, all looks like that, it changes just the content of a div (there are events inside).

Is it normal we see some degradation, in Edge is the worst, as the number of refreshes increase ?

Degradation : rendering time is getting bigger and bigger even though the DIV content is the same ( starts at 300ms and after a few hours 10 secs).

Is there a way to check for 'lost' events, divs or a smart tool to debug this kind of scenario ?

---

Refreshing the whole page can be an option but as it might take too long we can do this once per day.

Comment: Why don't you just refresh the content of the div without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: What do you mean by "degradation"?    In any case refreshing the full page every second just to update a single div is obviously a terrible idea -- among other things it makes user input basically impossible, because the page will keep refreshing out from under them.  Use an ajax request to only update the portion of the page that actually needs updating, and only when there is actually new data to display.

Comment: Its a bit unclear with what you mean with "degradation". I wouldn't just update the page every second, but wait at least till your previous request returns before doing a new request to avoid request handlers stacking up. (I asume you use ajax since you only update one div).

Comment: I think he wants to update every second to have some kind of live-update (for example in a chat) One solution would be to wait for the ajax response to come and for the response to render, then calling again. Also only updating when there is new content to display.